# Add special via foursquare api, got code 200 but special doesn't show up

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to add a special via the foursquare api  [Add special endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/specials/add).
I am generating a proper POST request and getting a similar response to what the api should return. But it still wont show up on the specials on foursquare.
Do I need to add a campaign too for it to show up?

This is the response object I am getting:

> {"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"special":{"id":"51ed8c2a498e821be0469850","type":"friends","status":"New
>   - in review","count1":10,"name":"Friends Special...!","text":"Everyone gets free cookies??","unlockedText":"hgc","autoRedeem":false}}}

Any ideas on what needs to be done?

PS: I am able to add a special manually on foursquare!!

This venue is an office and according to [this api doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/campaigns/add) offices and homes aren't allowed to add specials. This is a bit of a conflict.
Is it that offices are not allowed to add specials only via the API since I am able to create a special manually on foursquare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so, got the answer.. Create a special then create a campaign works!! 
But I'm still wondering how I was able to add a special when the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/campaigns/add) clearly says that homes and offices aren't allowed to do so!